# How to test update function in Rest API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit, mockito

I can't find a way to test my `update` method using JUnit. I am mocking the necessary repo and services. But when I call `findById(Mockito.any())` it can't find anything so it throws an exception.

Here is my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ApplicantServiceTest {


    @Mock
    private ApplicantRepository applicantRepository;
    @Mock
    private CreditRatingService creditRatingService;
    @Mock
    private ApplicantMapper applicantMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private ApplicantService applicantService;

    @Test
    void update() {
        Applicant applicant = getSampleApplicants().get(1);
        Applicant updatedApplicant = new Applicant(1L,2141245L,"ege","c0skun",2523,"21412412",null,null);

        Mockito.when(applicantService.update(applicantMapper.toDTO(applicant),Mockito.any())).thenReturn(applicant);

        Assert.assertEquals(applicant.getIdentificationNumber(),updatedApplicant.getIdentificationNumber());
        Assert.assertEquals(applicant.getPhoneNumber(), updatedApplicant.getPhoneNumber());
        Assert.assertEquals(applicant.getFirstName(), updatedApplicant.getFirstName());
        assertEquals(applicant.getMonthlyIncome(), updatedApplicant.getMonthlyIncome());
        Assert.assertEquals(applicant.getId(), updatedApplicant.getId());

    }
```

And this is the method I am trying to test:

```
  public Applicant update(ApplicantDTO applicantDTO,Long id) {

        Applicant byId = getById(id);

        if (applicantDTO.getMonthlyIncome()!=byId.getMonthlyIncome()){
            byId.setMonthlyIncome(applicantDTO.getMonthlyIncome());
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(applicantDTO.getFirstName(), byId.getFirstName())){
            byId.setFirstName(applicantDTO.getFirstName());
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(applicantDTO.getLastName(), byId.getLastName())){
            byId.setLastName(applicantDTO.getLastName());
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(applicantDTO.getPhoneNumber(), byId.getPhoneNumber())){
            byId.setPhoneNumber(applicantDTO.getPhoneNumber());
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(applicantDTO.getIdentificationNumber(), byId.getIdentificationNumber())){
            byId.setIdentificationNumber(applicantDTO.getIdentificationNumber());
        }

        return applicantRepository.save(byId);
    }
```

This is the output:

```
17:43:19.520 [main] ERROR com.egecoskun.finalproject.services.ApplicantService - Applicant not found by id : null

Related Applicant not found with : [id : null]
EntityNotFoundException(details=Some Special Details)
    at com.egecoskun.finalproject.services.ApplicantService.lambda$getById$0(ApplicantService.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at com.egecoskun.finalproject.services.ApplicantService.getById(ApplicantService.java:45)
    at com.egecoskun.finalproject.services.ApplicantService.update(ApplicantService.java:75)
    at com.egecoskun.finalproject.services.ApplicantServiceTest.update(ApplicantServiceTest.java:136)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

Can someone explain how to unit test my update method?

Comment: Please, add the fields from your test class to the attached code (including annotations over them). Also - you mentioned an exception is thrown - include the exception name and at least a shortened stack trace.

Comment: Why don't you have a `when` for the `findById` that returns the applicant? Why are you mocking the method you're trying to test?

Comment: You also haven't shown the code for the `getById` method, which is where the exception is being thrown, but presumably it's just calling `applicantRepository.findById`.

Comment: @DavidConrad Currently learning testing. Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: See the detailed answer by @Jonasz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your test code is that you've mixed mocking a method for a mock object (e.g. `applicantRepository`) with calling the tested method on an object under test (`applicantService`). We use `when(...)` to define the mocked behavior in Mockito and after that the actually tested code should be called (without the `when()`).

What you probably want to do is: mock retrieving the `applicant` object by ID, mock saving the modified object, run the `update` method to test it and assert the result.

To mock the behavior of the `applicantRepository` you need to tell Mockito what is the expected outcome of its methods calls, for example (I made a few assumptions for the code that is not attached):

```java
when(applicantRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(applicantFromDb);
when(applicantRepository.save(notNull())).thenAnswer(returnsFirstArg());
```

(`applicantFromDb` is an object created in the test method)

After that when you call your update method, the mocked behavior above will be used:

```java
Applicant result = applicantService.update(...);
```

Now you can assert the result returned from the tested method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which parameters I need to give to update method after mocking these I don't get it.

Comment: @EgeCoskun Since the repository is mocked to respond to `anyLong()` the `id` doesn't matter, but you should pass a valid `ApplicantDTO` for whatever you're trying to test.

Comment: The `applicantFromDb` object simulates an object that could be returned from the database, as per my knowledge about your code it could even be an empty object with all null values. The DTO passed to the `update` method is an object containing the values that should be set for the object before saving (updating) it in the database. You should test at least 2 paths in your code - all ifs conditions resolved as true and false, but it's usually advised to divide such code into multiple tests to make it easier to find bugs in the future (it narrows the potential erratic places in the code).

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. This answer solved the issue. Helped a lot sir !

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicationService` is your class under test. The exception you're getting is coming from `ApplicationService.getById()` method called at the start of `update()` method you're testing. You did not show us that method, but at a guess it calls the repository to get an instance by id. Your Repository mock is not set up to return anything when asked for any entity, so it returns null. Which seems to trigger the `orElseThrow` clause in the `getById()` method.

As such what you're seeing is likely the expected behaviour - when trying to update with an id that does not exist in the repository (repository returns null) service throws an exception. If you want to test the case where the entity is present you need to mock the repository appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give me an example of how I should test the method in code?

Comment: Uh... set up the repository mock as @Jonasz showed you, call the update method, and confirm that what it returns is what you expect should be returned.